# Autenticação de Grupo Middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

salve galera, quero saber como projeto minha rota admin para que o usuario não tenha acesso a essa rota mas eles dois tem que está autenticado.

### Minhas rotas

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get('/Admin', function () { //ADM ADM

        return "Seu ID: " . Auth::user()->id . " Você é ADM";

    })->name('admin');

    Route::get('/Usuario', function () { //USER USER

        return "Seu ID: " . Auth::user()->id . " Você é Usuario";

    })->name('usuario');

    Route::get('/semLogar', function () { // SEM LOGAR

        return "Você não está autenticado";

        })->name('semLogar');

    Route::get('/login/admin',['middleware' => 'Check:admin','uses' => 'AdminController@index', 'as' => 'indexAdm']);
});
```

### Meu controler

```
public function index (){

    return "Opa controller adm";
}
```

### Middleware

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {

```
    return redirect()->route('semLogar');

}
if(Auth::user()->role == $role){

    return redirect()->route('admin');

} else if (Auth::user()->role !== $role){

    return redirect()->route('usuario');
}

return $next($request);
```

}

### middlewareGroups

```
'CheckGrupo' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'Check' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin::class,
    ],
```

### routeMiddleware

```
    'Check' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin::class,
```

O que eu quero é que quando o usuário estiver logado ele não consegui colocar na URL /admin e entrar na rota /admin que ele só possa entrar se for adm.

OBS: estou cadastrando no banco um ENUM('usuario','admin').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode definir um grupo de rotas e adicionar o middleware desse jeito:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {

   Route::middleware('Check')->group(function () {

     // Rotas que só o admin pode acessar
   });

   // Demais rotas
});
```

Para o middleware do `Check` eu recomendaria o seguinte código :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if (Auth::user()->role == $role) {

         return $next($request);
    } 

    return redirect()->route('usuario');   
}
```

Como o middleware `auth` é executado antes desse middleware não é necessário verificar se o usuário está logado, e caso você tenha mais de uma página para o admin não vai querer redirecionar ele para rota `admin` toda hora.

Link da documentação:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-groups

Comment: vlw man ajudou muito GOD